# mongodb index on regex fields not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm new in mongoDB and I'm facing an issue about performance that need your help. I have a collection with 400k records, when not create index for any field on the collection it takes 20-30s for each query then I create indexs for fields that usually using for search query, but the problem is, when using $regex to search for a string field with index on it, mongoDB does not use index on that field, mongodb still scan for all records in that collection, I've searched on internet with this keyword: "index on regex fields mongodb" and I found some answers which say that "MongoDB use prefix of RegEx to lookup indexes" which means you have to use "^" prefix for the index to work like "db.users.find({name: /^key word/})", but that is not working for me, does "index on $regex field" need MongoDB Atlas to work? because i'm using comunity version of mongoDB. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for full regex search capability, or really just key word search?

Comment: hi @rickhg12hs, I'm looking for full regex search capability like db.users.find({name: {$regex: '.*keyword.*', $options: 'i'}})

Comment: I don't think the standalone version of MongoDB server will use an index in all circumstances of a `"$regex"`.  You may want to look at [`"$text"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) and the [notes on Index Use](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) for `"$regex"`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to unpack here. We'll split the answer into two parts, the first to try and answer some of the direct questions about index usage and the second to explore solutions to satisfy the application requirements.

#### Index Usage with $regex

As is true with an index in any database that captures the full string value as the key, MongoDB *can* use the index for a `$regex` operation but its efficiency in doing so greatly depends on the regex being applied. That is what the [Index Use documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) from the comments and the other answers you reference are describing.

In the comments you mention that an example query might be `db.users.find({name: {$regex: '.*keyword.*', $options: 'i'}})`. That means that the regex is a both unanchored and case-insensitive. The aforementioned doumentation states directly:

> Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively.

Why is this? because the substring that you are searching for can be found in any string value captured by the index. So the document with matching value `{name: 'a keyword'}` would be located at one end of the index, `{name: 'keyWord' }`, may be somewhere in the middle, and `{name: 'Z keyword'}` may be at the end. The only way to ensure correct results is for the database to scan the index for all string values. So while it is still using the index, it may not be efficient as most of the scanned values will not be match and will be discarded.

You may always use `.explain()` to better understand how the database is answering the query, such as if and how it is using an index.

#### Solutions

So what do we do about this?

Well as @rickhg12hs suggests in the comments, it depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve. You reiterate that that you are looking for '*full regex search capability*', but that is really an approach/solution rather than a goal. If what you really need, for example, is just to match an exact string in a case insensitive manner, then something as simple as a [case insensitive index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/) would likely do the trick.

However if truly do wish to perform arbitrary substring searching, then you are really looking at search engine capabilities. In that situation your best bets would probably be to emulate their indexes directly in MongoDB (e.g. have the application manually tokenize the strings to be indexed), stand up something like Solr/Elasticsearch next to MongoDB, or use MongoDB's Atlas Search offering. The `$text` operator mentioned in the comment has limitations when it comes to substring searching (such as just part of a word), which may or may not be relevant for your needs.